# Compare powers practice in javascript from codewars

Tags: javascript

I was working on this practice on Codewars.

These are instructions:
you have to build a function to compare powers,
 returning -1 if the first member is larger,
 0 if they are equal,
 1 otherwise; 
 powers to compare will be provided in the [base, exponent] format:
comparePowers([2,10],[2,15])===1 
comparePowers([2,10],[3,10])===1
comparePowers([2,10],[2,10])===0
comparePowers([3,9],[5,6])===-1
comparePowers([7,7],[5,8])===-1

This is my code, but it says this is wrong solution. I have no idea why it is not valid.

```js
function comparePowers(n1,n2){
  //your code here
  var one = Math.log(n1[0]) * n1[1];
  var two = Math.log(n2[0]) * n2[1];
  if (one > two)           return -1;
  else if (one < two)      return 1;
  else if (one == two)     return 0;
}

comparePowers([2,10],[2,15]) //1);
comparePowers([2,10],[3,10]) //1);
comparePowers([2,10],[2,10]) //0);
comparePowers([3,9],[5,6]) //-1);
comparePowers([7,7],[5,8]) //-1);
```

Successful answer is below:

```js
function comparePowers(n1,n2){
    if( n1[0] === n2[0])
      return ((n2[1] > n1[1]) ? 1 : (( n2[1] < n1[1] ) ? -1 : 0));
    if( n1[1] === n2[1])
      return ((n2[0] > n1[0]) ? 1 : (( n2[0] < n1[0] ) ? -1 : 0));

    var p1 = Math.log(n1[0]) * n1[1];
    var p2 = Math.log(n2[0]) * n2[1];
    return ((p2 > p1) ? 1 : (( p2 < p1 ) ? -1 : 0));
}
```

Comment: Does it give the correct result in all test scenarios? If so, it's valid. The fact that some random people on a (rather poorly worded) website think you should be throwing in a load of ternary operators is totally irrelevant.

Comment: A link to the exercise in question would be useful. The successful answer is certainly a better answer (because it shortcuts in the case of matching bases or matching exponents) but I doubt that's something they are testing for. *Unless*, in their own test environment they do something like wrap the `Math.log` function so they can check if you called it or not. But that would be pretty underhanded.

Comment: The only difference I've noticed is that yours should handle powers of 1 and numbers to the 0th power properly, but the other won't...

Comment: What is probably happening is that they have some "*hidden*" test cases where your function gives a different result. As @StephenTG pointed out, one case if the case of the zeroth power. However, in that case *your result* is actually correct.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments! Just in case you guys still want to check the kata by yourself! http://www.codewars.com/kata/compare-powers

Comment: @AnthonyGrist It was all valid except one of the test scenarios. The thing is they dont show me what test it was. That is why I was lost!

Comment: @StephenTG Thanks I will check it!

Comment: @MattBurland Ooo tricky hidden cases. Actually I had several similar problem before. Finally I can understand why it threw an error for codes(they passes all scenarios except one) that look totally correct!